# STRING_SPLIT on INNER JOIN takes different indexes and bad performance

Tags: string, split

I have a query using STRING_SPLIT on an INNER JOIN and it looks very different behaviours deppending on how i join.

**EXAMPLE 1** (11 seconds - 161K rows)

```sql
DECLARE @SucursalFisicaIDs AS TABLE (value int)
INSERT INTO @SucursalFisicaIDs
    SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT('16531,16532,16533,16534,16536,16537,16538,16539,16541,16543,16591,16620,17071',',')

SELECT ArticuloID, SUM(Existencias) AS Existencias 
FROM ArticulosExistenciasSucursales_VIEW WITH (NOEXPAND)
    INNER JOIN @SucursalFisicaIDs AS SucursalFisicaIDs ON SucursalFisicaIDs.value  = ArticulosExistenciasSucursales_VIEW.SucursalFisicaID 
GROUP BY ArticuloID
```

[image]

**EXAMPLE 2** (2 seconds - 161K rows)

```sql
SELECT ArticuloID, SUM(Existencias) AS Existencias 
FROM ArticulosExistenciasSucursales_VIEW WITH (NOEXPAND)
WHERE SucursalFisicaID NOT IN (16531,16532,16533,16534,16536,16537,16538,16539,16541,16543,16591,16620,17071)                                   
GROUP BY ArticuloID
```

[image]

Both Queries read from the view (it is indexed).

**EXAMPLE 3 (3 seconds - 161K rows)**

```sql
SELECT ArticuloID, SUM(Existencias) AS Existencias 
FROM ArticulosExistenciasSucursales_VIEW WITH (NOEXPAND)
INNER JOIN STRING_SPLIT('16531,16532,16533,16534,16536,16537,16538,16539,16541,16543,16591,16620,17071',',') AS SucursalFisicaIDs ON SucursalFisicaIDs.value = ArticulosExistenciasSucursales_VIEW.SucursalFisicaID 
GROUP BY ArticuloID
```

[image]

**EXAMPLE 4 (6 seconds - 161K rows)**

```sql
DECLARE @SucursalFisicaIDs AS TABLE (value int)
INSERT INTO @SucursalFisicaIDs
    SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT('16531,16532,16533,16534,16536,16537,16538,16539,16541,16543,16591,16620,17071',',')

SELECT ArticuloID, SUM(Existencias) AS Existencias 
FROM ArticulosExistenciasSucursales_VIEW WITH (NOEXPAND)
WHERE SucursalFisicaID NOT IN (Select Value  From @SucursalFisicaIDs)
GROUP BY ArticuloID
```

[image]

Can anyopne tell me why doesnt the first example work? It shoul be the same and better than the others. Is anything on the types i shlould do?
Note in example 4, the tablescan on SucursalFisicaIDs Table, the number of rows. (3M???)

Regards.

Comment: You do know that `INNER JOIN` and `NOT IN` are opposites, right? For queries like this, `INNER JOIN` is equivalent to `IN`, not to `NOT IN`. Try again, this time comparing apples to apples.

Comment: Andreas, sorry for the mistake.The NOT IN Clause was an IN clasue. But the problem is the same. I am asking about de SPLIT_STRING use, bad performace and bad index selection that the optimizer choose.

Comment: The short answer is that you should not use table variables if you care about plan choice. It is documented in a few places, including here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15